# Understanding the topology of Casson and Kinky Handles

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I am trying to understand kinky handles (and later on: Casson Handles itself) by means of Kirby Calculus. From Akbulut, I have learned roughly:

- 1-Handles can be drawn as unknots (with dots on it, to distinguish from 2-Handles). Geometrically, this can be seen as 2-handles removed from the 0-handle.

Sofar good, this indeed leaves us with a "nice enough" description of $M^4 = H^0 \cup H^1 \cup H^2 \cup nH^3$, when there are 2-handles and 3-handles present.

Now kinky-handles, what I can follow is that (with the simplest kink possible), we end up with:

[image: Whitehead Link]

With a dot on the unknot. Now comes the bit I cannot figure out. Most of the topologists I have seen say that, on symmetry basis, we can change the components by a simple isotopy, and just move the dot from the unknot to the self-linked component. On symmetry basis, I can see why this is preferred, but geometrically wise, we end up with a dot on the somewhat less trivial link.

The confusion is that most of the topologists say that a dot is only allowed on a unknot, which is strengthed by the geometric argument stated above. The closest explanation of the "knot with dot" is Gompf, who removed a neighbourhood of this, ending with s tacoshell-like environment. My questions:

- What is the geometric interpretation of the dot on the nontrivial component of the Whitehead.?
- Is it possible for a dot (meaning a 1-handfle) to occur on a non-trivial knot, or are arguments made to "make the pictture" and thus the Kirby calculus itself easier ?

Comment: You should consider reading the section on plumbings in Gompf-Stipsicz's excellent book: http://books.google.com/books/about/4_manifolds_and_Kirby_Calculus.html?id=ahLKzRUTBbUC In Chapter 6, they also describe what it means to have a dot on a ribbon knot.

Comment: For what it is worth, the Gompf-Stipsicz book is an excellent resource for Kirby calculus related matters.

Comment: Both components of the Whitehead link are unknots.